# Address of "empty" variadic template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template member function defined as:

```
template<typename ... Params>
 VAlgorithm* CreateAlgorithm(const char *objectName, const char *className, Params ... par)
```

and I would like to take the address of the specialized version where Params contains no type (which I call the "empty" specialization), ie., of:

```
VAlgorithm* CreateAlgorithm(const char *objectName, const char *className)
```

I tried in several ways. The naive way:

```
&AlgorithmFactory::CreateAlgorithm<>
```

(since, for example, &AlgorithmFactory::CreateAlgorithm< int > works) and a more explicit way:

```
(VAlgorithm* (*)(const char*, const char*))AlgorithmFactory::CreateAlgorithm<>
```

With the explicit way, GCC 4.7.1 says:

```
error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
```

It seems that the "empty" specialization is not understood by the compiler, which interprets the missing template types as a lack of info and not as "no types" information. What is the correct way to do this? (Sorry for the potentially naive question but I'm fairly new to variadic templates and I found no documentation on this topic).
Thanks

Comment: Could you post more of your code, e.g. the definition of `AlgorithmFactory` and the context where you're taking the address?

Comment: AlgorithmFactory is a class whith no parents; Createalgorithm is defined as:  template<typename ... Params>
  VAlgorithm* CreateAlgorithm(const char *objectName, const char *className, Params ... par). I'm trying to take the address from inside the main function.

Comment: You have declared `CreateAlgorithm` `static`, right?

Comment: No, I didn't. I can do it since AlgorithmFactory is meant to be a singleton. But why it works without static if I specify at least one type and conversely it requires static if I leave the types list blank?

Comment: The compiler *should* give you an error "invalid use of a non-static member function".  You should be taking a member function pointer `(VAlgorithm* (AlgorithmFactory::*)(const char*, const char*))`.

Comment: It doesn't give me any error when I specify at least one type. Indeed, my code ran without any problem up to today, when for the first time I tried to use the "empty" specialization.

Comment: That's undefined behaviour; you can't convert a pointer to member function to a function pointer (a `static` member function is not a member function).

Comment: Sorry ecatmur, I misunderstood your previous comment. Seems that this works: (VAlgorithm* (AlgorithmFactory::*)(const char*, const char*))&AlgorithmFactory::CreateAlgorithm<>. Many thanks, tomorrow I'll try to gothrough it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work; see e.g. http://liveworkspace.org/code/6253cf45f416be60879b93aa74c24de8

All the following syntaxes work for me:

```
struct S {
  template<typename... Args> static int *foo(const char *, const char *, Args...);
};

int main() {
    (int *(*)(const char *, const char *))S::foo<>;
    (int *(*)(const char *, const char *))S::foo;
    (int *(&)(const char *, const char *))S::foo<>;
    (int *(&)(const char *, const char *))S::foo;
    int *(&f)(const char *, const char *) = S::foo<>;
    int *(&g)(const char *, const char *) = S::foo;
    int *(*h)(const char *, const char *) = S::foo<>;
    int *(*i)(const char *, const char *) = S::foo;
}
```

Comment: It is the static keyword in the declaration of foo that makes everything compile smoothly. I compiled your example and indeed it works, but if you omit static then you get the same error about insufficient contextual information.

Comment: @NicolaMori easy mistake to make!